# Angular6 firebase get values triggered somany times

Tags: angular, firebase, opentok

[image]

This is my firebase structure. 
Under engagement participant each id has multiple key value pairs.

I want to check is session id is undefined or not.

I used the following code

```js
let fburl = '/meetinglist/350' ;

this.fbsub =  this.db.list(fburl).valueChanges().subscribe(res => {  
  if(res[1] != undefined) {
    console.log("session created")
  }
});
```

But here value changes event triggered multiple times. For value change event it also sense the `engagement_participant` node too. I just want to sense the `sessionid` and `token` only. But session and token created on run time. Initially this node doesnt appear. Engagement participant alone displayed. After session initialized it created the session and token node. Is there any way to proceed this.

This event triggered multiple times .... and `session created`  console displayed so many times. After page redirection the value changes event doent stopped. How to stop this event .

I used `this.fbsub.unsubscribe();`. But it is not working.

Please help me

Comment: What's the expected result? Stop the subscribtion? Trigger change only if `sessionId` and `token` change? Other?

Comment: @youri: Yes the expected result is both stop subscription and trigger only if session and token occurs

Answer (score 0):

As you subsrcibed to `/meetinglist/350`, you get an event on each `/meetinglist/350` update.
If you only want to subscribe to `token` and `sessionId` you could put your data in an object (if you can update the storage model) whith the following:

```js
{
  350: {
    tokens: {
      token: "...",
      sessionId: "..."
    }
  }
}
```

And subcribe to `/meetinglist/350/tokens` with:

```js
this.db.list('/meetinglist/350/tokens').valueChanges().subscribe( ... );
```

You can unsubscribe you list change with the following code:
([From angularfire2 rep](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/377))

```js
this.mySubcribtion = this.db.list('/meetinglist/350/tokens').valueChanges().subscribe(
  ...
);

// Later
this.mySubcribtion.unsubscribe();
```

> In some cases you may want a snapshot of your data without listening
>   for changes, such as when initializing a UI element that you don't
>   expect to change. You can use the once() method to simplify this
>   scenario: it triggers once and then does not trigger again.

You can do it with the following code:
([From angularfire2 rep](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/586))

```js
const sessionIdPromise = this.db.list(fburl).query.once('value');
const tokenPromise = this.db.list(fburl).query.once('value');
```